# How give permission to only create/edit stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

In my SQL Server 2008 database, how do I give permission to only create/edit stored procedures?

For example, one person is admin DB and obviously he can create, update, delete and insert data/procedures/etc.

But another person is only a system developer and he can create/edit stored procedures as db owner; that gives permission for CRUD entire DB - this is the issue!

With `grant alter on` the role can edit procedures after create one, but still needs db owner to create new ones

How to give permissions to a role/user only for managing stored procedures, either for create, edit, delete procedures and to read (just read) tables that will be used by the procedures?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you identify which schemas in which the stored procedures are allowed to be created. And then grant alter rights to that schema only.